# 2008 AP Calculus AB multiple choice

Tags: calculus

The function f is twice differentiable with f(2)=1, f'(2)=4, and f"(2)=3. What is the 
value of the approximation of f (1.9) using the line tangent to the graph of f at x = 2?

(A) 0.4 (B) 0.6 (C) 0.7 (D) 1.3 (E) 1.4

[image]

I understand the first part of the explaination, but I don't understand the part after OR.
Can someone please expalain how that works?